# IE10 switches to compability mode on most pages

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

This started just recently, IE10 switches to compatibility mode and one of two things happen, either that tab becomes unresponsive and I get a blank page or it only partially renders.

Is there any good way to figure out why it switches to compatibility mode? Ive searched everywhere and people only suggests resetting settings or just accepting that it doesnt work.

The thing is, Im 99% certain these sites worked a couple of days ago.

Sites that are broken in IE10:

- https://github.com/
- http://www.w3.org/
- http://www.ibm.com/

Can anyone view these sites in IE10/Windows8 without IE switching to compatibility mode?

I've tried resetting settings, deleting cache, restarting, upgrading windows, no change.

I've read somewhere that fonts might be the cause, is there any way to troubleshoot them?

**Update**

Ive tried everything mentioned by user2480011 below, but no luck.
Isnt there any way to repair or reinstall just IE10?

Pages like [FZ](http://www.fz.se) also looks like crap. No text, just a couple of images. It just switches *document mode* to *Internet Explorer 7* as soon as I load it. That doesnt happen at home for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours surfing I found the problem.
The problem was fonts, specifically Helvetica just like [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/525f5c56-7d65-45cb-a879-d283b010f888/ie10-and-blank-pages) guy.

So, basicly what I did was move all the fonts added/modified the last month. I had 104 Helvetica fonts. Anyway, after a restart everything works fine again.

Anyway, im [not alone](http://www.jlao.net/en/technology/1679/).

Answer (score 0):

On IE, go to Tools, then 'Compatibility View Settings' and ensure that "Display all websites in Compatibility View" is not checked on. Also, clear the history and internet data to make sure that you didn't accidentally click to view some of the websites to be opened in Compatibility mode.

Comment: Yeah, ive done that. Same error. I have never before been to IBM's website on this computer, I just went there to find an example site to illustrate the problem. Is there any way to repair/reinstall IE10 in Windows 8?